# Getting event when account is removed

Tags: nest-api

I have two questions:

1. I am using Firebase to get events from Nest thermostat.
   When a user is removing my client from his Nest account, do i get an event or some kind of notification (Account->Works with Nest->Remove Connection)?
2. I saw that there is another way to work with Nest instead of Firebase which is REST streaming. What is this feature? Can any one send me a link to a demo on how to use this with Nest?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's not immediate. Could take a few hours.